# Last UITableViewCell split into 3 buttons

Tags: uitableview

I have a tableview as a menu for my app. I want the very last cell to be 3 buttons that resemble a cell that has been divided into 3 sections. The National Geographic app does EXACTLY what i'm looking for:

[image]

How can I get the last cell to resemble what this does (the area with the three 0's)? Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add three UIViews with button in your last cell. In your method:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

create to identifier, one for simple cell and one for last cell:

```
static NSString *SimpleCellIdentifier = @"simpleCell";
static NSString *LastCellIdentifier = @"lastCell";
```

make a condition:

```
if(indexPath.row == lestIndexCell) {
    //create last cell with "lastCell identyfier", and add subviews
    [cell addSubview:buttonView1];
    [cell addSubview:buttonView2];
    [cell addSubview:buttonView3];

} else {
    //create last cell with "simpleCell identyfier"
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks! How can I disable the last cell from being tapped so I can have the custom views be tapped? Thanks again!